# looping problems in vbscript

Tags: sql-server, loops, for-loop, vbscript

I am trying to two files: 1. a text file with 6 lines containing a dealer code and number of unit sales per each line (eg. 010, 64). I splice out both elements and assign them to variables. Next, I am trying to loop through an SQL table and update the sales figures by matching the dealer code.

The problem I am having is the inner loop (the SQL update) updates the sales figures from each dealer in the outer loop for every row in the SQL table throwing off the numbers. For example, two dealers with their respective unit sales on lines 1 and 2 of of the text file : 010, 64 and 020, 72. The inner loop will update the first dealer with both sales figures (64 and 72), rather than the first and move on to update the second. I know the problem is in my construction of the loops. Any help is appreciated.

```vb
If fso.FolderExists(sourceLocation) Then
  Set fileList = fso.GetFolder(sourceLocation).Files 
  For Each fileFound In fileList
    Set folder = fso.GetFolder(sourceLocation)
    upd_date = CStr(FormatDateTime(Date(),2))

    If fso.FolderExists(sourceLocation) Then
      Set fileList = fso.GetFolder(sourceLocation).Files
      For Each fileFound In fileList
        If fso.FileExists(fileFound) Then
          Set ReturnNoFileToRead = fso.OpenTextFile(fileFound)                 

          Do While Not ReturnNoFileToRead.AtEndOfStream
            readLine = ReturnNoFileToRead.ReadLine
            If Not IsNumeric(Left(readLine,1)) Then
              alphaLine = Split(readline,",") 
              upd_date = Left(alphaLine(0),20)
              insertDate = "UPDATE soavehreports SET rep_date = '" + upd_date _
                + "' WHERE rep_type = 'CUR' "
              sneConnection.Execute(insertDate)
            ElseIf IsNumeric(Left(readLine,1)) Then
              intLine = Split(readline,",")
              intLine(1) = CInt(intLine(1))

              For row = 0 to RowCount -2
                distnum = Trim(tableArray(r, 0))
                daily = CInt(Trim(tableArray(r, 2))) + intLine(1)
                tenday = CInt(Trim(tableArray(r, 3))) + intLine(1)
                mtdsales = CInt(Trim(tableArray(r, 4))) + intLine(1)
                ytdsales = CInt(Trim(tableArray(r, 5))) + intLine(1)
                currinvt = CInt(Trim(tableArray(r, 8))) - intLine(1)
                totaval = CInt(Trim(tableArray(r, 9))) - intLine(1)
                mtdpercent = CDbl(Trim(tableArray(r, 12)))
                ytdpercent = CDbl(Trim(tableArray(r, 13)))

                UpdateCmd1 = "UPDATE vedlynat_new SET daily = '" + CStr(daily) _
                  + "', tenday = '" + CStr(tenday) + "', mtdsales = '" _
                  + CStr(mtdsales) + "', "
                UpdateCmd1 = UpdateCmd1 + "ytdsales = '" + CStr(ytdsales) _
                  + "',  currinvt = '" + CStr(currinvt) + "',  totaval = '" _
                  + Cstr(totaval) + "', proc_date = '" + upd_date + "' "
                UpdateCmd1 = UpdateCmd1 + "WHERE distnum = '" + intLine(0) _
                  + "' AND distnum <> '999'"
                sneConnection.Execute(UpdateCmd1)
              Next
            End If
          Loop

          ReturnNoFileToRead.Close
          sneConnection.close
        End If
      Next
    End If
```

Text File:

```
010,64
020,62
050,155
060,136
080,127
```

SQL Table:

```
distnum  daily  tenday  mtdsales  ytdsales
010      0      0       0         0
020      0      0       0         0
050      0      0       0         0
060      0      0       0         0
080      0      0       0         0
```

Comment: It would help greatly if you posted the table structure and a couple lines of sample data. I can't wrap my head around what you are trying to do here.

Comment: Thanks, put at end of code.

Comment: Umm...your sample data does not even come close to what it look like you are doing in code. Your sample data has only two values. In your code you have a number of columns across two tables. Unless you provide some details this is just guess work. You might take a look at this article for a good place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: in the sample data the second value gets added to each column

Comment: So all the columns have the same value?? That is not what your code does. This really shouldn't be too difficult but without some information it could take several round trips to figure out what you want.

Comment: the columns may have different values (I just zeroed them out to make the math easier), but each column will have the same sales number added to the existing value where the first value in the text file equals the distnum in the sql table

Comment: If you are trying to add the value from the file to the existing value you need to add it. You are simply setting it. "ytd = ytd + YourVariable"